# Change image size within a division

Tags: html, image, stylesheet

I have a division placed on the bottom of the page. I put an image into this division, but I don't know how to modify the image. The problem may be, that the inline style for `<img>` is setting modification rules for all images. I have an inline style sheet that has this code and HTML code for `<div>`.

My CSS code looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
 img {
      image-align: center;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 200px;
      width:  140px;
  }

 div {
     position: absolute;
     right: 10px;
 }
 </style>
```

And my HTML code is like that:

```
 <div align="center" >
     <img src="images/music_banner.jpg" >
 </div>
```

Comment: Well, what exactly do you want to change about the image? What's not working?

Comment: The inline `style` tag will affect all images _on that page_.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
div img{

}
```

or give the div a name and do this

```
#div img{

}
```

or you give the `img` an `id` as below

```
<div>
<img id="mg"/>
</div>
```

Use id as `#mg` in `CSS code`.

or you can do as define `class name` in `img` tag.

```
<div>
<img class="mg"/>
</div>
```

Use class as `.mg` in `CSS Code`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try learning a little bit more about **[CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)**: these are the rules that tell the browser which element you'd like to apply the following rules to.

I would recommend [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web) for an easy to follow course.  You can skip down to the CSS section if you are already comfortable with HTML.

Note: if you google CSS, you'll get "w3schools" as the first results. That website is generally derided on Stack Overflow. I don't know if it's really that bad, but I tend to skip it just because everyone else has a bad opinion of it.  Your call if you find it helpful of course.

I should note that I like to use the [W3C (World Wide Web Consortium) website](http://w3.org/) for reference, as they're the ones trying to make everything standard. It is a pretty technical read, though.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `div` element in your HTML code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="image">
</div>
```

Than add this to your CSS code:

```
.parent {
    width: 42px; /* I took the width from your post and placed it in css */
    height: 42px;
}

/* This will style any <img> element in .parent div */
.parent img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```